# Directory terminal shortcuts Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I use GIT from the command line and have to cd many times before getting to my desired directory. Is there a way to make a shortcut to a directory on a MAC OS X system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias gotomydir='cd ~/git/myproject/src/common/utils'
```

Creates a command line shortcut called "gotomydir" that does exactly what you want.  Add it to your .profile or .bashrc as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i wanted.